# How to Style List with image

Tags: html, css, facebook

How would you style this code so I would add a social media icon after the text?

```
<li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/3ndvorg/">Follow On Facebook</a></li>
```

I would like to add the Facebook image icon just after the "Follow On Facebook" text...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `background` to the `a` tag, like this:

```
.facebook a { 
   padding-right: 20px; 
   background: url(yourimageurl.png) no-repeat right;
}
```

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/swrf2/)

**EDIT:** [**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/uADfA/) with implementation to match image in comments.

Comment: +1, for the most reliable cross-browser supported method I think.

Comment: The above only worked for my facebook icon not the other icons in the list - here is what it looks like right now http://d.pr/7tuG

Comment: @user550408: you need to create a different CSS selector for each one : `.facebook a`, `.twitter a` and `.rss a`.  [Click for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/uADfA/).

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the "icon" as `img` tag:

```
<li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/3ndvorg/">Follow On Facebook&nbsp;<img src="path/to/icon.jpg" alt="Facebook Icon" /></a></li>
```

Or you could use something like:

```
.facebook a {
    background: url('path/to/icon.png') right center no-repeat;
    padding-right: 10px; /* icon width + some pixels for spacing */
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to style this = the code above worked for my facebook icon but using the same code above did not work for the other icons (of course changing the image and path..                                    <ul> <li class="facebook"><a href="facebook.com/3ndvorg/">Facebook</a></li>; <li class="twitter"><a href="twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>; <li class="rss"><a href="">Subscribe</a></li> </ul>